# Why does scrapy crawl quotes result in a GET error?

Tags: scrapy

I have generated the quotes spider in the tutorial, and I have added a yield option to parse. However, the spider is not working because it is having an issue downloading quotes.toscrape.com.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    allowed_domains = ["quotes.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        h1_tag = response.xpath('//h1/a/text()').extract_first()
        tags = response.xpath('//*[@class="tag-item"]/a/text()').extract()

        yield {'H1 Tag': h1_tag, 'Tags': tags}
```

2019-07-31 12:04:08 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/> (failed 1 times): []

```
2019-07-31 12:04:09 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]

2019-07-31 12:04:09 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]

2019-07-31 12:04:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/>




2019-07-31 12:04:07 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.7.2 started (bot: quotes_spider)
2019-07-31 12:04:07 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.4.0.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 19.2.1, Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48) - [Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019), cryptography 2.7, Platform Darwin-18.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2019-07-31 12:04:07 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'quotes_spider', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'quotes_spider.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['quotes_spider.spiders']}
2019-07-31 12:04:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: ab4784ba2a683680
2019-07-31 12:04:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-07-31 12:04:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-07-31 12:04:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-07-31 12:04:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-07-31 12:04:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-07-31 12:04:07 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-07-31 12:04:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-07-31 12:04:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2019-07-31 12:04:08 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/robots.txt> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2019-07-31 12:04:08 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/robots.txt> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2019-07-31 12:04:08 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/robots.txt>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aakankshasaxena/anaconda3/envs/API_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 44, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider)))
twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2019-07-31 12:04:08 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2019-07-31 12:04:09 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2019-07-31 12:04:09 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2019-07-31 12:04:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.quotes.toscrape.com/>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aakankshasaxena/anaconda3/envs/API_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 44, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider)))
twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2019-07-31 12:04:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-07-31 12:04:09 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 6,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 6,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 1362,
 'downloader/request_count': 6,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.28015,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 31, 19, 4, 9, 880266),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 6,
 'log_count/ERROR': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 50892800,
 'memusage/startup': 50892800,
 'retry/count': 4,
 'retry/max_reached': 2,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 4,
 "robotstxt/exception_count/<class 'twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived'>": 1,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 31, 19, 4, 7, 600116)}
2019-07-31 12:04:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should actually yield the correct result. The error was a syntax error.